# How to make a JSP page look like a desktop application?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have seen the UI of [OpenKM](https://www.openkm.com/) to prepare document management system in JSP. I am just asking how they make it looks like a desktop app with right click, drop down and so many features. Visit [this site](https://www.openkm.com/en/screenshots.html) to see more screenshots explaining and showing what I mean.

Is there any script being used or embedded in JSP which makes it look like a desktop app or it is only JavaScript with CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

The frontend of OpenKM is built as a website with styles (CSS) and JavaScript/jQuery to make it look and feel like a desktop application. I have seen several other web-application that try to imitate this. A modern trend is going in the opposite direction by using web technologies to build desktop apps with frameworks such as [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org).

Since the source code of the *OpenKM Community Edition* is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/openkm/document-management-system), you can see yourself how they did it. There is also a Docker image so you can run it locally to see the UI in action and get some inspiration:

```
docker run --rm --name openkm-ce -p 8080:8080 openkm/openkm-ce
```

<sup>(URL: `http://localhost:8080`*, user: `okmAdmin`, password: `admin`)</sup>

*Screenshot with Web Inspector open:*

[image: screenshot]